# import .md file error to render vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, meteor, vuejs2

I base on `Meteor + Vue` .
I try to import .md file to render vue template .

```js
<template>
       <VueMarkshow :source="mdFile"></VueMarkshow>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMarkshow from 'vue-markdown'

import mdFile from './README.md'
export default {
  name: 'VueMarkdown',
  components:{VueMarkshow},
}
</script>
```

But it get error :

```js
 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
    return module.dynamicImport('./Vue-Markdown.vue');
  }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module './README.md'
```

Comment: I was struggling with this for a while but finally gave up. I suspect that your problem is that you don't have a loader for md files. I used pure Vue-CLI and I received all the error `"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"`.

Comment: Vue-Cli is work , but when I used in `Meteor` project it's not work and I used raw-loader config with `webpack.config.js` and I don't know it's wrong of my config or what.

Answer (score 2):

You can't **import** an ordinary file like this:

```
import mdFile from './README.md'
```

because **import** is only for javascript code. - So we need to read the file in some other way.

It is not particularly easy to read files from client javascript code.
You can use FileReader, which is HTML5 stuff, but you can't ask to read a file directly - for security reasons you have to first ask for the file from a file `<input>`.

However you *can* read a file from your /public folder. So if your README.md is in your /public folder you can do an ajax request as follows:

```
       var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
       client.open('GET', '/README.md');
       let self = this;
       client.onreadystatechange = function() {
           self.mdFile = client.responseText;
       }
       client.send();
```

Then you need a variable (I've called it `mdFile`) to hold the string result of the ajax call in your data() function, which we will then place in the '**source**' parameter of **vue-markdown**.

Here is the complete code, which I have tested, and it works:

```
<template name="appLayout">

    <div>
        <vue-markdown :source="mdFile"></vue-markdown>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
    import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown';

   export default {
       data() {
           return {
               mdFile: '',
           };
       },
       components: {
           VueMarkdown
       },
       created() {
           var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
           client.open('GET', '/README.md');
           let self = this;
           client.onreadystatechange = function() {
               self.mdFile = client.responseText;
           }
           client.send();
       },
   }


</script>
```

Please note that vue-markdown has some kind of weird problem with babel, and there's an old bug still open in github. I found that I had to install babel-runtime twice:

```
meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

#### Do no use Meteor for building

This solution has two steps:

1) Replace Meteor building system by webpack

> https://medium.com/the-guild/meteor-with-webpack-in-2018-faster-compilation-better-source-handling-benefit-from-bc5ccc5735ef

2) Use loader for markdown for webpack

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-loader

#### Load markdown file on backend

This is simpler to achieve and I have sample of my code:

1) On front I display computed html from markdown

```
              <div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
```

2) I have defined computed property:

```
  computed: {
    compiledMarkdown: function() {
      return marked(this.DOC_CONTENT, { sanitize: true });
    },
  },
```

When `marked` is library that convert markdown to html

```
import marked from "marked";
```

3) My `DOC_CONTENT` is loaded from backend:

```
  created() {
    Meteor.call("get_docs", (err, res) => {
      this.DOC_CONTENT = res;
    });
  },
```

4) On backend there is defined method

```
Meteor.methods({
  'get_docs'() {
    return Assets.getText("CHANGELOG.md");
  }
})
```

5) And my file `CHANGELOG.md` is located in `/private` folder in root of meteor project.

```
/private/CHANGELOG.md
```